# What game this crane avatar from?

Tags: game-identification

I am using this avatar for my PSN account.

[image: crane]

Can anyone tell me what game is it from?

Comment: Help us narrow this a bit. Is this a premium avatar (one downloaded from the store) or is it one of the default avatars included with the system? When roughly did you set it? If it's a premium avatar, you could probably find it in your download list and look for its "official" name.

Comment: It is avatar from default set, not premium or specially downloaded. I have choose it while creating my PSN account about half a year ago.

Comment: I've loaded the PSN avatars and searched for your avatar, I've found it just before a couple of avatars from the game "Anomaly: Warzone Earth". I assume it is from the same game as well, but not sure, that's why I suggest you try Googling for a bit just to find out if it's the correct game.

Comment: Could it be Transformers: Fall of Cybertron?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Anomaly: Warzone Earth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anomaly:_Warzone_Earth)

It's a unit from the tower defence game.